# Dynamic id assign to collapsible div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a set of records stored with in a SQL database which I pull and display these on the page using PHP and HTML. That is all well a good but I'm trying to create a collapsible div to hide all of the extra information about that record. When trying this all the divs close for all records and not a single record, so the question is how do I assign a unique id to each individual div (say named each Record name pulled by the database.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$chNumber = $record['CH_NUMBER'];?>

<div id="prof_prod" <!--style="display: none;"-->>
    <div class="groupbox showgraph">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title-container">
                <div class="title">Part Number: <i id="partNumber"></i><?php echo $record['CH_NUMBER'] ?></div>
                <div class="title">Serial Number: <i id="serialNumber"></i><?php echo $record['SERIAL_NUMBER'] ?></div>
                <div class="title">Status: <i id="status"></i><?php echo $record['CH_NUMBER'] ?></div>
                <div class="title">Current WIP Time: <i id="wipTime"></i><?php echo $record['WIP_TIME'] ?></div>
                <div id="<?php echo $chNumber; ?>" class="button info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="data-container">
        <div class="data-row">
           <div class="data-title">NC Number: </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("echo json_encode($chNumber)").click(function(){
        $(".data-container").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Now I know there maybe generic HTML errors here but that's from me copying the code and taking some stuff out (apologies). My question is based around the line:

```
<div id="<?php echo $chNumber; ?>" class="button info"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></div>
```

And:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("echo json_encode($chNumber)").click(function(){
        $(".data-container").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are echoing json_encode in your javascript.

Comment: Someone told me to at work...completely new to this so please bare with me :) thank you for the heads up though :)

Comment: @demonLaMagra : Praveen already clear in his answer how you can use it. What else you need

Comment: Thanks for your support @urfusion!

Comment: @Praveen Kumar. Sorry if i seemed I was being ungrateful, really wasn't being. I was just expressing how I'm personally really struggling with learning this. I appreciate all of the help from you all :-) Over the night I've tried many different things and can still not get this to work...I think I'm going to write the page from scratch to see if it's anything i have done.

Comment: @demonLaMagra Awesome... Let me know, I can personally help you with this. `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar. Here is something strange. So I'm using the example http://jsfiddle.net/vFnqp/281/ to go back to basics.

Now if i copy this code directly with the addition of the style and script tags my code doesn't. How is that even possible. JavaScript does not like me.

Comment: @demonLaMagra That's working perfectly fine. What's strange?

Comment: edited my comment above :)

Comment: @demonLaMagra What does it say in the Console?

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar.
   'code'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @demonLaMagra Ha! Either you are not including jQuery or you execute jQuery dependent code before the library is loaded.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar. Ha, you were correct lol! Will try the code posted last night now to see if it works :)

Comment: @demonLaMagra hope it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have seen how it renders. The code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<?php echo $chNumber; ?>").click(function () {
        $(".data-container").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

I don't understand the use of `json_encode` here. But you are definitely missing `<?php ?>` tags.

Also, try using `this` instead of `'.data-container'`, which selects everything. So, you might be using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<?php echo $chNumber; ?>").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".groupbox.showgraph").next(".data-container").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Just tried your second lost of code and still no luck (although the data is displayed to the screen a lot faster :) I really must have gone wrong some where else really not sure what I'm doing to be honest

Comment: Kumars post answers the question but generates a lot of unecessary code, take a look into my answer below for improvement.

Comment: @DennisHeiden Call me `Praveen`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS for every single record here.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.button.info").click(function(){

        var i = $(this);

        //$('.data-container').slideUp(); //uncomment this line to close every other container

        i.closest('.groupbox.showgraph').next('.data-container').slideToggle('slow');

    });
});
</script>
```

I recommend to use a logical html structure here:

```
<div class="list-container">

   <div id="i<?php echo $chNumber;?>" class="item">

      <div class="header">

       // intro text / information
       <button class="control">More</button>

      </div>

      <div class="body">
         // more content here
      </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var buttons = $('.list-container button.control');    

        buttons.click(function(){

             var btn = $(this);
             var item = btn.closest('.item');

             item.find('.body').slideToggle('slow');

        });    

    });
</script>
```

1. Use at least one letter in the beginning of the id attribute for elements if you add numbers dynamically.
2. Don't repeat yourself and your code if that code provides the same functionality again over again.
3. Using classes to identify your container helps to write global functions to manipulate them.